# How to zip lists only if they of the same size and fail if their sizes differ?

Tags: scala, collections

Suppose I am writing a function to zip two lists only if they are of the same size and fail otherwise:

```
 def foo(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int]): Either[String, List[(Int, Int)]] =
    if (xs.size == ys.size) Right(xs zip ys) else Left(s"$xs and $ys have different sizes")
```

It works but I don't like using `if`. How would you improve the code above ?

Comment: Looks good to me. You have to use condition anyway. Alternative could be pattern match on size, but I don't think it brings much value `def foo(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int]): Either[String, List[(Int, Int)]] = xs.size == ys.size match { case true => Right(xs zip ys) case false => Left(s"$xs and $ys have different sizes") }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern matching if for some reason you don't like `if`

```
def zip(as: List[Int], bs: List[Int]): Either[String, List[(Int, Int)]] = (as, bs) match {
    case (Nil, Nil) => Right(Nil)
    case (a :: as1, b :: bs1) => for {
      t <- zip(as1, bs1)
    } yield (a, b) :: t
    case _ =>  Left(s"$as and $bs have different sizes")
  }
```

or

```
def zip(as: List[Int], bs: List[Int]): Either[String, List[(Int, Int)]] = {
    @tailrec
    def loop(as1: List[Int], bs1: List[Int], acc: List[(Int, Int)]): Either[String, List[(Int, Int)]] = (as1, bs1) match {
      case (Nil, Nil) => Right(acc)
      case (a :: as2, b :: bs2) => loop(as2, bs2, (a, b) :: acc)
      case _ => Left(s"$as and $bs have different sizes")
    }

    loop(as, bs, Nil).map(_.reverse)
  }
```